# Mount TP-Link network drive

Tags: command-line, server, mount, tp-link, network-drive

I have a *TP-Link Archer VR600* router, I connected a USB drive to it and I want to mount it to my **Ubuntu Server** (terminal only).

[image: archer vr600 network drive configuration]

I installed `cifs-utils`.

I tried many variants of `sudo mount -v -t cifs -o username=guest,password=,vers=1.0 //192.168.1.1/{Archer_VR600|sda1|volume|volume1|<empty>} /mnt/share`, but no luck.

Without `vers=1.0` I get `CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -22`

With `vers=1.0` I get `CIFS: VFS: cifs_mount failed w/return code = -6`.

I can't find any solution for that.

Comment: Do you that that device supports SMB and what version if it does?

Comment: @David I'm not sure: https://www.tp-link.com/en/home-networking/dsl-modem-router/archer-vr600/#specifications All the FAQs are considering there is `smb`, but they are not talking about the specific model: https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/732/

Comment: As @David mentions, there are some restrictions on the versions of SMB that are usable due to being insecure. Might be that despite specifying `vers=1.0` either Ubuntu or the remote machine (your archer)  will reject it.
In general I must admit that it is frustrating to find a proper list of these error codes...

Answer (score 0):

`tp-link axe75 axe5400` uses `vers=2.0` I'm not sure about your model.  I found that out from tp-link support.

this worked for me:

```bash
sudo mount -v -t cifs -o username=admin,password=xyz,vers=2.0 //192.168.1.1/g /media/stuff
```

You'll notice I didn't include anything about the MyShare name that the router assigns and tells you to use for windows samba sharing.

Which ends up in `fstab`:

```bash
//192.168.1.1/g /media/stuff cifs noperm,auto,defaults,nofail,username=admin,password=sdfsdf,vers=2.0 0 0
```

Comment: Thanks! What is the `/g` in `//192.168.1.1/g`?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment hence this answer but consider this a suppliment (comment) to the query asked for explanation of /g in answer given by Phox+baruchiro :

So the default drive letter is assigned by router which is **`g`** in case of tp link router normally. So your path to access the usb attached to router assuming router ip address is `192.168.1.1` will be : `smb://192.168.1.1/g` for explorer while using cifs utilities just use `//` as stated in the answer. Unless you do not change this in the router firware which needs custom firmware (assuming you use router as is from the manufacturer in this case tp-link) the drive letter cannot be changed.

[Router Settings Preview for USB setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ2qg.png)

There might be some models which might use different letter but idea remains the same and is not something you can modify.

So your root (parent) folder of the usb storage device attached will be accessible using `smb://ipaddress/g` while sub directories(folders inside) can be acces as `smb://ipaddress/g/foleder1`  or `smb://ipaddress/g/folder1/xyz` etc and so on.

Also to mount the tp-link usb it depends on how old the router model and firware is . If you have updated firmware and a fairly new (2-5 years old) router, they should work with smb2.0 but if they don't then try 1.0 for older ones. Newer routers do get newer versions as my tp-link old router updated to latest firmware support upto 2.0.
Hope that answers som queries and explains enough.

Have a good one ahead!